# Make Lambda expression with a generic data type C#

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I need to know if is posible to have a lambda expression that receive a generic datetype for the object in such a way that I could to order using a string, int or datetime,  actually I have this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T,int>> id, int page, int qty)
    {
        try
        {           
            int skip_ =  PaginationMetering(page, qty);

            return dbSet.OrderBy(id).Skip(skip_).Take(qty).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException ?? e;
        }
    }
```

I have tried this, but my problem is that i can't make the datatype casting when the function is execute:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T,dynamic>> id, int page, int qty)
    {
        try
        {           
            int skip_ =  PaginationMetering(page, qty);

            return dbSet.OrderBy(id).Skip(skip_).Take(qty).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException ?? e;
        }
    }
```

If possible, how can I approach it? this is important because it prevents me from repeating the same function for several types of data

Comment: Where is `dbSet` coming from?

Comment: Can't you add another type parameter? `public virtual IEnumerable<T, K> GetMany(Expression<Func<T,K>> id, int page, int qty)`? Or can you show some examples of how you are calling this?

Comment: A [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your OrderBy come from but use the same signature for your own method.
For example:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
```

And for your example:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TSource> GetMany<TSource, TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> id, int page, int qty)
```